# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{bx-\arctan(bx)}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I struggle with solving this with L'Hospital technique:

> $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{bx-\arctan(bx)} \tag{1}$$

It should be:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{a-\dfrac{a}{a^2x^2+1}}{b-\dfrac{b}{b^2x^2+1}} \tag{2}$$

I end up with:

$$\frac{a-a/1}{b-b/1} \tag{3}$$

Which is $0/0$.

Just the same as if I didn't use l'Hospital method.

Same if "tan" is used instead of "arctan".

Yet, it seems it is solvable.

Any clue in order to get me on the right path?

Thanks.

Comment: *L'Hospital* would be better.

Comment: I don't know, I translate literally in english what I use in French :-)

Comment: I am French and I always learnt and used *L'Hospital*. Just our of curiosity, may I ask where you are located ?

Comment: A single application  of L'Hopital's Rule and some simplification gives you the answer.

Comment: I saw an autograph of the guy once.  He wrote *Lhospital*.  Of course the conventions of French spelling have changed in the past 250 years.

Comment: Sure, but a family name hardly changes over the years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use

$$a-\dfrac a{a^2x^2+1}=\dfrac{a^3x^2}{a^2x^2+1}$$

Alternatively

Using [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{(ax)^3}=\dfrac13$$

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't your numerator still produce a zero when applying the limit?
PS: I don't see anything that resemble to my case in your link and I don't understand how the last line produces a 1 on the numerator. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri, By your method $$\lim_{x\to}\dfrac{a^3x^3}{b^3x^3}=?$$

Comment: @BachirMessaouri, Using my link, 
$$\dfrac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{bx-\arctan(bx)}=\dfrac{a^3}{b^3}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{(ax)^3}}{\dfrac{bx-\arctan(bx)}{(bx)^3}}$$

Comment: I spoke too soon. I still don't see it. How are you having a^3x^3/b^3x^3 from your line above (with a^3x^2)? I'm lost.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri,  Do you know $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac hh=1?$$

Comment: I see that you can simplify x^3/x^3 but how did you get there from a^3x^2/a^2x^2+1 (sorry, I really try)?

Comment: @BachirMessaouri  $$a-\dfrac a{a^2x^2+1}=\dfrac{a(a^2x^2+1)-a}{a^2x^2+1}=?$$

Comment: This one I got. it's the transition from "a^3x^2/a^2x^2+1"  to" ^3^3" that I don't (thank you for your patience)

Comment: @BachirMessaouri,  Take out $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{b^2x^2+1}{a^2x^2+1}$$

Comment: I start to see where you are going and why you end up with a^3/b^3 by simplifying. What's beyond me is why you would take those two out (in your last comment) as what you are taking out is mixing b^2 and a^2. How in the world can you simplify "b^2x^2+1/a^2x^2+1....." and get 1/1?. Obviously it's there in front of my face and I don't see it.

Comment: Ok, this charade thing, piece by piece got me confused. Now I see it. You cancel out  the extra pieces AFTER applying the limit which leaves you with the a^3/b^3. I was understanding that you made the simplification before applying the limit which got me very confused. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {ax - \arctan (ax)} {bx - \arctan (bx)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {a-a/(1+a^{2}x^{2})} {b-b/(1+b^{2}x^{2})}$. Simplify this ratio.  The limit is $\frac {a^{3}} {b^{3}}$ since the ratio  simplifies to $\frac {a^{3}} {b^{3}} \frac {1+b^{2}x^{2}} {1+a^{2}x^{2}}$ after cancelling $x^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hesitated to consider your answer as the one (because it is), but lab bhattacharjee made the effort to tell the same thing you did repeatedly. I just didn't get it right away. Thanks!

Comment: @BachirMessaouri My intention was only to point out that instead of directly putting $x=0$ after one application of L'Hopital's Rule you could have done some simplification to get the answer. My comment has nothing  to do with voting or approval. I think you were right in approving Lab Bhattacarjee's answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{bx-\arctan(bx)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(ax-\arctan(ax)\right)}{\sin\left(bx-\arctan(bx)\right)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(a x)-a x \cos(ax)}{\sin(b x)-a x \cos(b x)}\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2x^2}}{\sqrt{1+a^2x^2}}
$$

now discarding $\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2x^2}}{\sqrt{1+a^2x^2}}$ we follow with

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(a x)-a x \cos(ax)}{\sin(b x)-a x \cos(b x)}
$$

Applying l'Hopital twice now, we obtain easily as result

$$
\frac{a^3}{b^3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You just keep on applying L'Hopital's rule. After three times you will get$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ax-\arctan(ax)}{bx-\arctan(bx)}=\frac{2a^3}{2b^3}=\left(\frac ab\right)^3.$$

Comment: It appears that single applcation of the Theorem is enough.

Comment: I didn't know we could use the derivative technique multiple times and still get a valuable answer.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri But you can.